# Ruby - Redis based mutex with expiration implementation

Tags: ruby, multithreading, locking, redis, mutex

I'm trying to implement a memory based, multi process shared mutex, which supports timeout, using Redis.

I need the mutex to be non-blocking, meaning that I just need to be able to know if I was able to fetch the mutex or not, and if not - simply continue with execution of fallback code.

something along these lines:

```
if lock('my_lock_key', timeout: 1.minute)
  # Do some job
else
  # exit
end
```

An **un-expiring mutex** could be implemented using redis's `setnx mutex 1`:

```
if redis.setnx('#{mutex}', '1')
  # Do some job
  redis.delete('#{mutex}')
else
  # exit
end
```

But what if I need a mutex with a timeout mechanism (In order to avoid a situation where the ruby code fails before the `redis.delete` command, resulting the mutex being locked forever, for example, but not for this reason only).

Doing something like this obviously doesn't work:

```
redis.multi do  
  redis.setnx('#{mutex}', '1')
  redis.expire('#{mutex}', key_timeout)
end
```

since I'm re-setting an expiration to the mutex EVEN if I wasn't able to set the mutex (`setnx` returns 0).

Naturally, I would've expected to have something like `setnxex` which atomically sets a key's value with an expiration time, but only if the key does not exist already. Unfortunately, Redis does not support this as far as I know.

I did however, find `renamenx key otherkey`, which lets you rename a key to some other key, only if the other key does not already exist.

I came up with something like this (for demonstration purposes, I wrote it down monolithically, and didn't break it down to methods):

```
result = redis.multi do
  dummy_key = "mutex:dummy:#{Time.now.to_f}#{key}"
  redis.setex dummy_key, key_timeout, 0
  redis.renamenx dummy_key, key
end
if result.length > 1 && result.second == 1
  # do some job
  redis.delete key
else
  # exit
end
```

Here, i'm setting an expiration for a dummy key, and try to rename it to the real key (in one transaction).

If the `renamenx` operation fails, then we weren't able to obtain the mutex, but no harm done: the dummy key will expire (it can be optionally deleted immediately by adding one line of code) and the real key's expiration time will remain intact.

If the `renamenx` operation succeeded, then we were able to obtain the mutex, and the mutex will get the desired expiration time.

Can anyone see any flaw with the above solution? Is there a more standard solution for this problem? I would really hate using an external gem in order to solve this problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Redis 2.6+, you can do this much more simply with the Lua scripting engine. The [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) says:

> A Redis script is transactional by definition, so everything you can do with a Redis transaction, you can also do with a script, and usually the script will be both simpler and faster.

Implementing it is trivial:

```
LUA_ACQUIRE = "return redis.call('setnx', KEYS[1], 1) == 1 and redis.call('expire', KEYS[1], KEYS[2]) and 1 or 0"
def lock(key, timeout = 3600)
  if redis.eval(LUA_ACQUIRE, key, timeout) == 1
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      redis.del key
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
lock("somejob") { do_exclusive_job }
```

Comment: I'm thinking that in your code snippet, `r` and `redis` are referring to the same thing.

Comment: Good catch! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [redis 2.6.12](http://redis.io/commands/SET#options) you can do: `redis.set(key, 1, nx: true, ex: 3600)` which is actually `SET key 1 NX EX 3600`.

I was inspired by the simplicity that of both Chris's and Mickey's solutions, and created gem - [simple_redis_lock](https://github.com/nitzanav/simple_redis_lock) with this code(and some features and rspec):

```rb
def lock(key, timeout)
  if @redis.set(key, Time.now, nx: true, px: timeout)
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      release key
    end
  end
end
```

I explored some other awesome alternatives:

1. [mlanett/redis-lock](https://github.com/mlanett/redis-lock)
2. [PatrickTulskie/redis-lock](https://github.com/PatrickTulskie/redis-lock)
3. [leandromoreira/redlock-rb](https://github.com/leandromoreira/redlock-rb)
4. [dv/redis-semaphore](https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore)

but they had too many features of blocking to acquire lock and didn't use this single `SET KEY 1 NX EX 3600` atomic redis statement.